# Can't use multiplication in arithmetic expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 3 ] ;then
        echo "USAGE : calculate.sh VAR1 OPERATOR VAR2"
exit 1
fi
VAR1=$1
OP=$2
VAR2=$3
if [ $OP = '+' ];then
        echo "$VAR1+$VAR2=$[$VAR1+$VAR2]"
        exit 0
elif [ $OP = '-' ];then
        echo "$VAR1-$VAR2=$[$VAR1-$VAR2]"
        exit 0
elif [ $OP = '*' ];then
        echo "$VAR1*$VAR2=$[$VAR1*$VAR2]"
        exit 0;
else
        echo "$VAR1/$VAR2=$[$VAR1/$VAR2]"
fi
```

The above is the content of `calculate.sh`.

If I use `+`, `-`, or `/`, I get the correct answer, but when I use `*`, it reports an error：

> ```
>  kdyzm@kdyzm:~/scripts$ ./calculate.sh 2 + 3 
>  2+3=5
>  kdyzm@kdyzm:~/scripts$ ./calculate.sh 2 - 3 
>  2-3=-1
>  kdyzm@kdyzm:~/scripts$ ./calculate.sh 2 * 3
>  ./calculate.sh: line 21: 2/command.sh: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".sh")
>  kdyzm@kdyzm:~/scripts$ ./calculate.sh 2 / 3 
>  2/3=0
>  kdyzm@kdyzm:~/scripts$
> ```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Put double quotes around `$OP`

Comment: Use `$((...))`. `$[...]` is an obsolete, no longer documented, pre-POSIX syntax for arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as pointed by others the fact than the character * is interpreted by your shell, be it in your terminal or your script. You must use backslash to make the shell understand it is really the character '*'.

Here is a complete solution.
Please, notice the condition `[ $# -ne 3 ]` rather than `[ $# -le 3 ]`and the condition `[ $OP = '\*' ]` rather than `else`. It is very bad practice to let unasked cases to go through. Doing so may cause hard to debug situations as you have now experienced.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
        echo "USAGE : calculate.sh VAR1 OPERATOR VAR2"
    exit 1
fi

VAR1=$1
OP=$2
VAR2=$3

if [ $OP = '+' ]
then
        echo "$VAR1+$VAR2 = "$(expr $VAR1 + $VAR2)
elif [ $OP = '-' ]
then
        echo "$VAR1-$VAR2 = "$(expr $VAR1 - $VAR2)
elif [ $OP = '\*' ]
then
        echo "$VAR1*$VAR2 = "$(expr $VAR1 \* $VAR2)
elif [ $OP = '/' ]
then
        echo "$VAR1/$VAR2 = "$(expr $VAR1 / $VAR2)
else
    echo "Operator must be +-*/"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Which gives :

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ ./calculate.sh 6 '+' 5
6+5 = 11
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ ./calculate.sh 6 '-' 5
6-5 = 1
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ ./calculate.sh 6 '\*' 5
6*5 = 30
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ ./calculate.sh 6 '/' 5
6/5 = 1
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ ./calculate.sh 6 '*' 5
./calculate.sh: line 13: [: too many arguments
./calculate.sh: line 17: [: too many arguments
./calculate.sh: line 21: [: too many arguments
./calculate.sh: line 25: [: too many arguments
Operator must be +-*/
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ ./calculate.sh 6 * 5
USAGE : calculate.sh VAR1 OPERATOR VAR2
```

Not perfect but much easier to debug.

Comment: Though a `case` statement would seem more natural here.  You forgot `exit 0` in the multiplication case.

Comment: The requirement to quote *and* backslash the asterisk is a bug.  One or the other should suffice.  This can be fixed by properly quoting `$OP` everywhere; or, as suggested above, with a `case` statement.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: @tripleee I began from original poster question and tried to get something similar. I added exit 0 at the end of the script thank to your recommandation. Otherwise, I would just send arguments to expr.
Quoting and escaping the asterisk is my way of coding, it's to your preference. I find it easier to reread.

Comment: Very much belated addition: to avoid the error message `[: too many arguments`, just (properly) quote `"$OP"` (and of course `"*"`) in the `elif` (eg `elif [ "$OP" = "*" ] ...` or avoid the problem altogether by using the modern bash double-bracket syntax feature: `elif [[ $OP = * ]] ...`

Answer (score 2):

You have to quote the arguments when you want to pass a `*`:

```
./calculate.sh 2 \* 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `*` character in bash is special and is returning a list of files. So instead of `2 * 3` you are getting a lot of files in addition to what you expect.

If you do an `echo "$@"` at the top of your script you'll see the actual parameters. On my system you get:

```
2 dump.xsl t.sh test.awk test.c test.cpp test.py test.sh 3
```

So my `$var2` ends up being `t.sh` and causes a syntax error. If you want to pass in a reserved character you need to quote it: `./calculate.sh 2 \* 3`

Comment: In addition to this ,i have to put double quotes around $OP ，otherwise the problem is still.